# Ignore new lines in regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

That is my pattern:

```
^[ A-Za-z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_.,#:&+-]*$
```

it accepts those chracters and spacse.

But i also want to have new lines.User can enter new lines such as

```
asdasda
asdasda


asdasdsa
```

What should i do?

this is my regex

https://regex101.com/r/N3Dbrz/3

I want to accept new lines but want all string as without new lines. In the link it is accepting without new lines.

So, the example should be recorded as

```
asdasda asdasda asdasdsa
```

not with new lines

I am using javascript, angularjs. in my javascript, it is like this:

```
vm.addressTextPattern = /^[ A-Za-z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_.,/#:&+-]*$/;
<textarea rows="5" ng-disabled="true"
         name="billingCompanyAddress"
         ng-model="vm.model.billingAddress.line1"
         ng-required="true"
         ng-minlength="15"
         ng-pattern="vm.addressTextPattern"
         maxlength="255"
         md-maxlength="255"></textarea>
```

Comment: have you tried changing your space to `\s`?

Comment: You could at least add `\n` and/or `\r` there if you do not want tabs and other types of whitespace. Do you want to allow tabs?

Comment: Your example link has no new lines in it. Also add the language you are using the regex in.

Comment: Okay, use multi-line mode and require something be present maybe? https://regex101.com/r/N3Dbrz/4

Comment: Use [this one](https://regex101.com/r/6dtMmt/1) and then `.split(/[\r\n]+/).join(" ")`.

Comment: "Ignoring while matching" is not supported by any regex engine. You have to use a 2 step approach.

Answer (score 0):

A regex cannot "skip" parts of a string within one match operation. So, what you need is a multi-step approach:

```js
var s = "asda sda\nasdasda\n\n\nasdasdsa";
var re = /^[ A-Za-z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_.,#:&+-]*$/;
console.log("Original string:", s);
var isValid = s.split("\n").every(function (t) {return re.test(t); });
console.log("Valid:",isValid);
if (isValid) {
 console.log("Record with no LF and empty:", s.split("\n").filter(Boolean).join(" "));
}
```

Note you may use a regex like

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_.,#:&+-]*(?:\n+[ A-Za-z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_.,#:&+-]*)*$/
```

to validate the whole multiline input. See [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/6dtMmt/2). Then, you'd replace `isValid` code part to

```
var isValid = /^[ A-Za-z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_.,#:&+-]*(?:\n+[ A-Za-z0-9ığüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ_.,#:&+-]*)*$/.test(s);
```

Still, you will have to replace the line breaks after that with spaces. `s.split("\n").filter(Boolean).join(" ")` may be replaced with a regex like

```
s.replace(/\n+/g, " ")
```

**NOTE**: To support `\r\n`, `\r`, and `\n` line break styles, replace `split("\n")` with `split(/\r\n?|\n/)`, `\n+` with `(?:\r\n?|\n)+`.